# Collection view not showing images properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In `view B` I have an imageview which can have an image from gallery. The image is stored in coredata as `NSData`

Now if I click on a submit button & return back to a `view A`, I have a `collectionview` where I want to display the image. If I again go to `view B` and add another image, click on submit & return to `view A` I should see 2 different images.

But when I return, what I’m seeing is the first image twice instead of 2 different images. But when I run the app again I see all different images
as required...
In viewWillAppear of `view A` this is what I’ve done…

```
//Fetching from Database
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Customers2")

do {
    customerDetails2 = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Customers2]

    for result in customerDetails2 {

        if let imageData = result.value(forKey: "image") as? NSData {

        }
    }
    collectionview2.reloadData()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

In `numberOfItemsInSection` of view A….

`count1 = customerDetails2.count`

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `view A`…

```
let dfg = customerDetails2[indexPath.row]

let asd = dfg.image

if let image = UIImage(data: asd! as Data) {
    imageArray.append(image)
    cell1.customerImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: `imageArray.append` (inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) smells very bad

Comment: ok..so what should have been there instead of that..?

Comment: but even I've done `imageArray.append(image)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is With the below line

```
 imageArray.append(image)
```

As you mentioned the issue occurs after adding the second image
So you might be reloading the collection view again to show the  images.
 The above code will be executed again and it will append the image for the row zero at the index 1 and row 1 at index 2 so when you try to show the image for row1, it will be same as row 0 ..
Use a dictionary if you want to cache the images 
like below

```
//Declare a poperty
var imageDict = Dictionary<String,UIImage>()

//At cellForRow

 imageDict["\(indexpath.row)"] = image
```

also check if the image exists in cache

```
 if let image  = imageDict["\(indexpath.row)"] as? UIImage {

   //Load Image    
 } else {

 //Initialise from data
}
```

Comment: Ok @Akhil..Thanks. But there's a concern. What shall I add into `imageDict` and how shallI add it..?

Comment: you can use the indexpath.row as the key i update answer with more info

Comment: Thanks @Akhil. It worked! have given an upvote too...:) Also, could u just say a word on what exactly was causing the problem initially..? Didn't fully get what u said..

Comment: you were not clearing the array before reloading .So content will be appended to array ever time cell for row gets fired